# Get string of certain length out of a list

Tags: python, string, list

What I am after is like this:

```
list1 = ["well", "455", "antifederalist", "mooooooo"]
```

Something that pulls `"455"` from the list because of the number of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator:

```
>>> list1 = ["well", "455", "antifederalist", "mooooooo"]
>>> 
>>> next(s for s in list1 if len(s) == 3)
'455'
```

`next()` also lets you specify a "default" value to be returned if the list doesn't contain any string of length 3. For instance, to return `None` in such a case:

```
>>> list1 = ["well", "antifederalist", "mooooooo"]
>>> 
>>> print next((s for s in list1 if len(s) == 3), None)
None
```

(I used an explicit `print` because `None`s don't print by default in interactive mode.)

If you want *all* strings of length 3, you can easily turn the approach above into a list comprehension:

```
>>> [s for s in list1 if len(s) == 3]
['455']
```

Comment: For the failure mode, you can also specify a default if you don't want it to raise StopIteration.

Comment: @wim Yes, that's a very good point. I'll add it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering how this stacks up to just defining a function that uses a `for` loop to run through `list1` and returns the first value with `len` of 3? A quick test in `timeit` shows that going much faster but....

Comment: @adsmith I wouldn't expect there to be much of a difference. What times did you measure? I bet if you use a larger list, the times will look less different.

Comment: @adsmith Try adding a `* 100` after the lists.

Comment: `b` still beats `a` by about 0.5s

Comment: Interesting timings.  What if the "hit" is towards the end of a long list?

Comment: @wim running now, with `list1 = [0]*10000; list1.append(1)` and grabbing `s==1`. Will update.

Comment: @wim (and @arshajii) generator is about 2s slower, with about 8 minutes per `timeit`

Comment: @adsmith So they're essentially the same.

Comment: @arshajii at least for long lists where the hit is at the end. For short lists or for lists with a quick "out", the `for` loop with a shortcircuit is 25% faster. Sounds like Big O is the same but the shortcircuit considerably drops the constant.

Comment: @adsmith The generator approach is also short-circuit; we only consume from the generator until we get an appropriate string. The time is probably being taken up by constructing the generator (which doesn't take long).

Comment: @arshajii I'm not questioning that, but since the `for` loop doesn't have to build a generator, the majority of which is never used....

Comment: @adsmith But building the generator is a constant-time process, it doesn't depend on the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(lambda s: len(s) == 3, list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you're looking to pull all items out of the list greater than some length:

```
 list2 = [string for string in list1 if len(string) >= num_chars]
```